# why is PHPhotoLibrary performChanges creationRequestForAssetFromVideoAtFileURL so slow?

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, photokit

I'm measuring times from tens of seconds to minutes depending on the size of the video. Shouldn't this change request be fast (local flash disk copy/meta data/checksums) as it adds a local video to the photolibrary/camera roll? **This issue appears to occur when iCloud backups are turned on.** I haven't been able to find much helpful information through web search or the apple dev docs.

Sample code:

```
    func exportAssetToPhotoLibrary(videoURL: NSURL, _ exportedAsset: (localIdentifier: String) -> Void) {
        var localIdentifier = ""
        var startTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
        PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().performChanges({
            let assetRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideoAtFileURL(videoURL)
            let assetPlaceholder = assetRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset
            localIdentifier = assetPlaceholder.localIdentifier
        },
        completionHandler: { success, error in
                var elapsedTime: NSTimeInterval = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate() - startTime
                NSLog("exported cameo video to photo library \(elapsedTime)")
                exportedAsset(localIdentifier: localIdentifier)
        })
    }
```

Comment: I have the same issue reported, but unable to get the repro steps.